# Does anyone know what technique was used in Minecraft to create shadows?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es2, minecraft-modding, shadows

Specifically I want to know the technique used to render shadows under animals and players.

I would like to create shadows like that for my own block game but I don't even know what to google.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a form of dynamic light"maps". The block contains its current lighting level, an additional shader takes that and smooths it + adds Ambient Occlusion. **Guesswork**

Comment: @akaltar OP asks about mobs' shadows, not blocks lighting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking  "what technology some particular game used" are off topic. I suggest you edit the question to describe the effect you're after (pictures are good too) and tell us what you've tried and what about it isn't working.

Comment: Are the shadows under players and animals not just static transparent circles drawn on the tile under the entity from a .png image? Like so: http://up.picr.de/13069441lj.png